# Socket.io emit is undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

**I am creating a zoom clone by following a tutorial on YouTube. In the project we are using socket.io and I am completely new to socket.io and just knew about this when doing the project. So when I start the Program it throws a type error `socket.to(roomid).broadcast.emit('user-connected');`  `TypeError: Cannot read property 'emit' of undefined` and I am not able to solve that can anybody help me.  **

Server/app.js

```js
io.on("connection", socket => {
    socket.on("join-room", (roomid) => {
        socket.join(roomid);
        socket.to(roomid).broadcast.emit('user-connected');
    });
});
```

client side JavaScript (script.js)

```js
const socket = io("/");

const myVideo = document.createElement('video');
const videoGrid = document.getElementById("video-grid");
console.log(videoGrid);
let myVideoStream

navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({
    video: true,
    audio: true
}).then(stram => {
    myVideoStream = stram;
    addVideoStream(myVideo, myVideoStream);
});
socket.emit("join-room", ROOM_id);
socket.on("user-connected", () => {
    connectToNewUser();
});

const connectToNewUser = () => {
    console.log("new user");
}
const addVideoStream = (video, stream) => {
    video.srcObject = stream;
    video.addEventListener('loadedmetadata', () => {
        video.play();
    });
    videoGrid.append(video);
}
```

I have required the socket.io script in the room.ejs. When I run the Program it have the following error.
[image: Here is the error.]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Syntax in app.js for:

```
socket.to(roomid).broadcast.emit('user-connected');
```

should be:

```
socket.broadcast.to(roomid).emit('user-connected');
```

Comment: Thank you very much.

Comment: @HassanShah If it helped. you can accept the answer and close it.